# Postgresql Insert into server from local using dblink

Tags: postgresql

I am connecting postgres in 192.168.4.12 I want to insert into table in server IP 192.168.4.13, I have tried but I get error.

ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute command.
********** Error **********

```
ERROR: syntax error at end of input
SQL state: 42601
Context: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute command.
```

Here is the syntax.

```
SELECT dblink_exec
    ('hostaddr=192.168.4.13 dbname=mrp-pti-coba user=postgres password=passwordb', 
        'insert into mst_item(item_id) values 
        (dblink_exec("hostaddr=192.168.4.12 dbname=mrp-exp2 user=postgres password=passworda","select item_id from mst_item")');
```